# With data.table in R, how do I efficiently replace multiple column values named within a single column?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

In R, I have a data table with a column ("prncl_diag") that has values of diagnoses. These diagnosis values (in the prncl_diag column) all appear as columns in the data table as well. There are ~2.5K diagnosis columns of which a subset appear as values in the "prncl_diag" column.

I want to update the diagnosis indicator columns with a 1 if its name appears in a given row of "prncl_diag" column.

That isn't explained too well, but here is a minimal working example.

```
dt <- data.table(heart_failure = c(0, 1, 0),
             kidney_failure = c(1, 0, 0),
             death = c(1, 1, 1), 
             prncl_diag = c('heart_failure', 'kidney_failure', 'death'))

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  name <- dt[i, prncl_diag]
  dt <- dt[i, eval(name) := 1]
}
```

This code works and updates row 1 of "heart_failure" to a 1, updates row 2 of "kidney_failure" to a 1, and doesn't change row 3 of "death" column as it is already 1.

However, the code is slow with a data table of 5M rows and I know I am not utilizing the structure of data.table.

Please advise for more efficient solutions. Interested to learn about R, data.table, and efficiency from the StackOverflow community.

Comment: An efficient `base R` option would be `setDF(dt);
 dt[cbind(1:nrow(dt), match(dt$prncl_diag, names(dt)))] <- 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to subset by unique values in `prncl_diag`.

```
for (val in unique(dt$prncl_diag)) {
  dt[prncl_diag == val, (val) := 1]
}
```

That's the way I would probably go about it, especially if there is a small number of unique values in `prncl_diag` relative to the number of rows.

Result:

```
#    heart_failure kidney_failure death     prncl_diag
# 1:             1              1     1  heart_failure
# 2:             1              1     1 kidney_failure
# 3:             0              0     1          death
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, Erik. One problem with this is that I have thousands of diagnosis columns; sorry for not specifying in the question, I updated. Thus, I don't want to have to name the specific columns. Also, is this dcast really faster? I imagine it could be slower than looping through all the rows?

Comment: Hey Erik -- I totally missed your first solution when I first skimmed this! Too many Stack averts! I ended up using your first solution. It is fast. I have 440 uniquie values to 5 million rows. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the portion of the answer using `dcast`. It doesn't scale well given the update to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(1:nrow(dt), ~dt[.x,] %>% mutate_at(vars(.$prncl_diag), function(y) ifelse(y==0,1,y)))

  heart_failure kidney_failure death     prncl_diag
1             1              1     1  heart_failure
2             1              1     1 kidney_failure
3             0              0     1          death
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Do you think this will be faster than the solution proposed in the comment to my question? Will save me timing both!

Comment: this does not work. I receive the following error. I convert it to a data frame before as well.

Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  .$prncl_diag

Comment: I added `library(tidyverse)` just in case...I don't get an error...are you using your full real data? Or your toy example data?

Comment: `akrun` answer is faster

Answer (score 1):

I think this'll achieve what you want.

```
> dt[, .SD
     ][, rID := 1:.N
     ][, melt(.SD, id.vars=c('prncl_diag', 'rID'))
     ][prncl_diag == variable, value := 1
     ][, dcast(.SD, prncl_diag + rID ~ variable, value.var='value')
     ][, rID := NULL
     ][]

       prncl_diag heart_failure kidney_failure death
1:          death             0              0     1
2:  heart_failure             1              1     1
3: kidney_failure             1              1     1
>
```

Comment: Btw, `rID := .I`